# Rolles theorem word problem - find the c - double checking my answer

Tags: rolles-theorem

**Problem:** 
Find the relationship of $a$ and $b$ so that Rolles theorem applies for the function $f(x) = ax^2 + b(\ln x)$ on $[1,e]$. Find the value of $c$ for which it is verified.

**Answer:**
the relationship between $a$ and $b$ is $b = a(1 - e^2)$
the value of $c$ is $c = \pm\frac 1 2\sqrt{e^2 - 1})$

I would like to double check my answer on this problem 
Any feedback would be appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: As long as $a$ and $b$ are opposite in sign, the first derivative would be $2ax + \frac{b}{x}$.  To make it zero, multiply $x$ on both sides, so that $x = -b/2a$ will give the extremum.

Answer (score 1):

Since $f(1)=a$ and $f(e)=ae^2+b$, one condition is $f(1)=f(e)$, so $b=a(1-e^2)$.

The function is indeed differentiable on $[1,e]$, so for $b=a(1-e^2)$, Rolle's theorem applies.

Since
$$
f'(x)=2ax+\frac{a(1-e^2)}{x}
$$
you just need to find $x\in(1,e)$ such that $2ax^2+a(1-e^2)=0$.

If $a=0$, there is obviously no problem. If $a\ne0$…